# Get total hours, minutes with relativdelta

Tags: python, odoo

How with relativdelta get total played time for Ronaldo and Messi?

Eg.

```
ronaldo = relativedelta(years=0, months=0, days=0, hours=0, minutes=92)
messi = relativedelta(years=0, months=0, days=0, hours=0, minutes=91)
```

total = 3 hours 05 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add them together:

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import *
>>> 
>>> r1 = relativedelta(minutes=91)
>>> r2 = relativedelta(minutes=92)
>>> r1 + r2
relativedelta(hours=+3, minutes=+3)
```